# Spring webflow + CAS : AuthenticationViaFormAction class is not called

Tags: java

My application uses CAS 3.4.11, Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.
My login-webflow.xml uses spring-webflow-2.0.xsd and the login flow is given below,

```
<var name="credentials" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentials" />

   <on-start>
     <evaluate expression="initialFlowSetupAction" />
   </on-start>

   <view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="casLoginView" model="credentials">
     <binder>
       <binding property="username" />
       <binding property="password" />
     </binder>
     <on-entry>
       <set name="viewScope.commandName" value="'credentials'" />
     </on-entry>
     <transition on="submit" bind="true" validate="true" to="realSubmit">
        <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.doBind(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials)" />
     </transition>
   </view-state>
```

The beans "initialFlowSetupAction" and "authenticationViaFormAction" are defined in cas-servlet.xml as,

```
<bean id="initialFlowSetupAction" class="org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction"
        p:argumentExtractors-ref="argumentExtractors"
        p:warnCookieGenerator-ref="warnCookieGenerator"
        p:ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator-ref="ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator"/>

  <bean id="authenticationViaFormAction" class="org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction"
        p:centralAuthenticationService-ref="centralAuthenticationService"
        p:warnCookieGenerator-ref="warnCookieGenerator"/>
```

The issue here is, the InitialFlowSetupAction is called while launch the login page. On click of "Sign In" button the bind/submit method of AuthenticationViaFormAction class should be invoked. But always the InitialFlowSetupAction is called and the form is redisplayed with out any exception. Atleast I could track if there is an exception.

Can it be a binding issue with username and password fields of the form to set its properties to UsernamePasswordCredentials?

Basically I would like to know why InitialFlowSetupAction is invoked onclick of "Sign In" button?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is because your form does not hold value of "_flowExecutionKey" field. 
It should contain next input elements to be able to resume flow execution.

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
</form>
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0-m1/reference/flow-executor.html

In CAS 3.5.2 for some reason field "execution" is used instead of "_flowExecutionKey".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting validate to false:

`<transition on="submit" bind="true" validate="false" to="realSubmit">`